# Laravel blade sections inside an included view (bladeception)

Tags: templates, laravel-4, laravel-blade

Im having problem with my blade structure. I have a base layout template, a content page template and sub templates.

take the following snippets as your reference

**base template**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    @include('head')
</head>

<body>
@include('body-open')
@yield('main')
@include('footer')
@include('body-close')

</body>
</html>
```

**content template**

```
@extends('base')
@section('main')
    content

@include('my-other-section-that-has-another-section-declaration-inside')

@overwrite

@section('body.script')
this is an extended script
@stop
```

**body-close template**

```
@section('body-open')
    this is the original content
@stop
```

**my-other-section-that-has-another-section-declaration-inside template**

```
this is cool

@section('body-open')
    @parent
    this should append to body open.
@stop
```

this is my expected result

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

</head>

<body>
this is the original content
this should append to body open.

content

this is cool
</body>
</html>
```

But im getting this content instead

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

</head>

<body>
this is the original content

content
this is cool

</body>
</html>
```

Notice that the line *this should append to body open.* has been skipped and doesn't append to its intended section.

Am I doing something wrong with my code? Or is this approach possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your includes order.

You're loading this partial: `my-other-section-that-has-another-section-declaration-inside template` first:

```
@section('body-open')
    @parent
    this should append to body open.
@stop
```

in the above you're trying to call `@parent` - but this one is empty so you will have only this in the *body-open* section: `this should append to body open.` for now.

After this: `@include('body-close')` you'll get:

```
@section('body-open')
    this is the original content
@stop
```

...without `@parent` call - so you will overrides this section with: `this is the original content` - and thats all you can expect here. You can try to fix it like this:

```
@section('body-open')
    this is the original content
    @parent
@stop
```

Comment: alright, will get back to you on this. Thanks @filip-koblański for your answer